# How to get handle to a TextBox control inside window in Window 10

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10, spy++

I am working on automation to Windows 10 with C#.
One of the tasks is to write data to a TextBox in window called "Add exclusion".

In order to enter this window:
Open Settings => Update & security => Windows Defender => Add an exclution => Exclude a file extension

I understood that I need to use `SendMessage(...)` or `SetWindowText(...)` functions for writing data to a control.
But I need to pass these functions a handle of the control I want to write to.
So I need to use `GetDlgItem(hDlg, nIDDlgItem)`.
The parameter `nIDDlgItem` is the control ID but I am not able to find the control ID of the TextBox control in the "Add exclusion" window.

I used Spy++ but when I put the target icon I received only "Shell_Dialog" class:
[image]

I have only the window handle:
[image]

I need the handle of the TextBox control.

**EDIT (20.6.2016):**
I tried to use the Inspect.exe tool from Windows 10 Kit but when I am placing the curoser on the TextBox control it writes me "Access is denied":
[image]

References:
[SetText of textbox in external app. Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100605/settext-of-textbox-in-external-app-win32-api)
[Inspect (Inspect.exe) is a Windows-based tool that enables you select any UI element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried to run Inspect.exe "as administrator"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to do it I needed to use the Inspect.exe tool with administrator permissions.

Thanks @NineBerry,
After I opened the Inspect.exe as administrator I could see all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Third alternative is to select parent (ie. dialog window) for your button (ie. it will be of Dialog class), and register for WM_COMMAND messages from it. Then after pressing it you button ID will be displayed as wID: XX in message window.

Source: [Using visual studio's spy++ tool:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185519/using-visual-studios-spy-tool)