# How to find another apps button handle? Visual Studios 2019

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to click a button an another program after I send info over from my application. I'm using AppActivate to send the info over with Sendkeys. It works great, but sends the other program (Game) into the pause menu. How can I tell my VB app to click that unpause button? I'm finding in my web search that there is a way to find the "Button Handle" of the button in the other program. I am still a beginner so it helps to see examples, but it seems like everyone just posts single lines of code like this "`SendMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);` or they say you can find the button using Spy++
Can some point me in the right direction? Explain how to use these.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using visual studio's spy++ tool:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185519/using-visual-studios-spy-tool)

Comment: This is completely dependent upon **HOW** the other program (game) was written.  It's possible that the "button" does not have a handle at all, and is simply rendered on the screen as normal graphics.  We would need more information about the game.  A screenshot ~might~ be helpful.

Comment: There are two different versions. C++ is one, and Java is the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have Spy++ or an equivalent tool, try this out real fast.

Drop a PictureBox and a Label on a Form.  Run it and drag the picturebox over the button in your other app to see if it has its own handle.

If it does have its own handle, then you'll need to use various APIs to get the handle based on the apps main window handle.

If it doesn't have a handle, then your "best" bet would be to get the upper left corner coordinate of the main window handle, then click on the screen (using APIs again) at a fixed offset from that corner where the button would be.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private prevHandle As IntPtr
    Private prevRC As Rect

    Public Structure PointAPI

        Public X As Integer
        Public Y As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
            Me.X = x
            Me.Y = y
        End Sub

    End Structure

    Public Structure Rect
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal pt As PointAPI) As IntPtr
    Public Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As Rect) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
        PictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        MessageBox.Show("Drag the PictureBox around the screen...")
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            prevHandle = IntPtr.Zero
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim pt As New PointAPI(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
            Dim handle As IntPtr = WindowFromPoint(pt)

            Label1.Text = handle.ToString("X")

            If Not handle.Equals(prevHandle) AndAlso Not prevHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
                ' erase previous rectanlge
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(New Rectangle(prevRC.Left, prevRC.Top, prevRC.Right - prevRC.Left, prevRC.Bottom - prevRC.Top), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick)
            End If

            If Not handle.Equals(prevHandle) Then
                ' get new rectangle
                GetWindowRect(handle, prevRC)

                ' draw new rectangle
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(New Rectangle(prevRC.Left, prevRC.Top, prevRC.Right - prevRC.Left, prevRC.Bottom - prevRC.Top), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick)
            End If

            ' store new handle
            prevHandle = handle
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(New Rectangle(prevRC.Left, prevRC.Top, prevRC.Right - prevRC.Left, prevRC.Bottom - prevRC.Top), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Thick)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That is super cool! I'm assuming you set the transparency to red to get a window to select through. It worked but I get a different number from the same button every time I use it. How do I fix that?

Comment: The "highlight" is just the ~frame~ (the middle isn't transparent, it's literally not there).  See [ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawreversibleframe?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The handle **will** be different every time you run the app, as it is assigned by windows when the control is created.  In general, it will stay the same for the lifetime of the app, but this won't necessarily always be true.

Comment: So, the Handle is not what I need to know to click a button on another program, outside my VB program?