# How to Click a button on another program from a button on my form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that does some calculations when a button is pushed. It sends the info to another program with AppActivate and SendKeys functions. But I need to now press a button on the other application to complete this transaction. I have the location of the button on the screen, but I'm not sure how to code the actual clicking of the button. If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find another apps button handle? Visual Studios 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58995249/how-to-find-another-apps-button-handle-visual-studios-2019)

Comment: UI Automation provides an [InvokePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern) to activate the default action of controls, no matter whether the control has a handle (WinForms/Win32) or not (WPF/UWP). The default action of a Button generates a Click event. You can also attach an event handler to the click event to have feedback when the event is triggered.

Comment: It did answer that question, but I don't think the handle is what I need now. If it can change from session to session, how can you use the Handle in your code?

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case perhaps [Enumerating Windows/Controls of another application from .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280818/enumerating-windows-controls-of-another-application-from-net) would be useful.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I will start researching that. Thank you